# Quick and slim way to automate upload of files to an Azure WebJob

Tags: java, azure, zip, cloud, azure-webjobs

I'm prototyping an **Java** program and start it via **Microsoft Azure** as a **WebJob**.
Since there are a lot of changes I often have to the following:

1. Delete the old WebJob via the webinterface
2. Create the new WebJob via the webinterface

   - Typing a Name
   - Upload my *.zip file
   - Accept the upload
3. Open the protocol site and watch the output of my command line

As a programmer, I ask myself:

> How can I automate this repetitive task in a slim way without loosing
>   too much time into writing another full-sized program for this task?

Answer (score 2):

There is an API on the Kudu endpoint that will let you directly upload your zip file in the right place. See https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API for details. Look for "Upload a triggered job as zip" and "Upload a continuous job as zip" in there (depending on your type of WebJob).

Also, see the top of https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API for general information on calling Kudu APIs.